# Highcharts y-axis's max value is not what I expect it to be

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please look at this highcharts yAxis config:

```
yAxis: [{
  max: 4,
  tickAmount: 4,
  tickInterval: 1,
  endOnTick: false
}],
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TedLilljegren/8fx9u9v7/

As you can see, the fiddle display a column graph using highcharts.js.
My problem is this:
The min value of the yAxis is 0, makes perfect sense, but the max value is 6!
Why is that?
I have set the max value of the yAxis to 4, which is less than 6, and in addition I have set a tickInterval of 1, with a tickAmount of 4, which ought to result in a maximum y extreme of 4!
The yAxis being in an array has no bearing on this problem as far as I know, neither does endOnTick.
I'd be really grateful if someone could help me make sense of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `tickAmount` the axis `max` value may be extended; from the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.max):

> If a tickAmount is set, the axis may be extended beyond the set max in
>   order to reach the given number of ticks. The same may happen in a
>   chart with multiple axes, determined by chart.alignTicks, where a
>   tickAmount is applied internally.

If you remove `tickAmount` your `max` value won't be affected.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: [{
    max: 4,
    tickInterval: 1
  }],
  chart: {
    type: "column",
  },
  series: [{
    data: [9, 0, 1]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I promisie I've read the docs but the meaning of the words eluded me...